Tub Damaged during removal...usable or needs replacement?
In the process of having a bathroom remodel (toilet flooding issue requiring subfloor replacement), but was planning to keep the tub. During removal, the tub lip/flange seems to have been damaged. Obviously, there should be a screw in that corner, but is that damage minor enough that the tub is still usable? Or do I need to ask the contractor to replace?



Sorry, but this is a matter of opinion. That makes it off topic. Please see the [help].

what do you mean seems to have been damaged ... it has been damaged

I would call that a usable tub. Nothing would keep the tub from holding water.
The flange is the only damaged part. It will be unseen. The missing part is not critical to mounting.  I have unpacked brand new fiberglass tubs that have worse damage.

I would not accept it because, if you look closely (bottom pic), it appears that the crack penetrates the flange and runs below the curb on the inside of the tub. That curb is meant to catch incidental splashed water and keep it in the tub; the crack will (potentially) allow water to get behind the tub.

This is why you want to make sure your contractor has liability insurance. If they do, they will either replace it themselves to keep their rates down, or their insurance will. It is damage that they have professional liability for causing, unless they opened up the wall and found the tub already installed with that damage (in which case they should have ocumented that, then and there, before starting removal.) If not, you find yourself arguing with the contractor about clearly sub-standard "professional" work.
